# What's the best way to remove features from DrawIO?

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I'm currently working with Draw IO (based on the MXGraph library) and need to remove a lot of features to fit the specific needs of the site I'm working on.
For reference, I cloned the source code (https://github.com/jgraph/drawio) and am running it with a Docker image.
Specifically, I want to: 
- remove the right side pane
- remove all of the shapes apart from a few
- remove the toolbar

Something similar to the image below:

[required end product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7dv4.png)

The code is super complicated and everything seems interconnected so I'm having problems locating the right sections of code. If anyone has worked with Draw IO in the past and knows how to do this, please let me know.
I have limited experience working with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can also start with the GraphEditor itself.
It is a very good starting point for your project.

[mxGraph-GraphEditor](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/tree/master/javascript/examples/grapheditor)

Answer (score 0):

You can start with a [mxGraph](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph), it's a base of draw IO. It is possible to achieve all your requirements using it.

EDIT: documentation is available [here](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/)